# Browser does not load angular app component

Tags: angular

Here's my index.html file and main.ts file. The browser just shows "loading..." and doesn't loads the component that i have created. Please help me out.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js">
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js">
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'>
</script>
<!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
  System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<blog>Loading...</blog>
</body>
```

main.ts

```js
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { SignInComponent } from './Login/SignIn/signin.component';
import { SignUpComponent } from './Login/SignUp/signup.component';
import { routing } from './app.routes';

@NgModule({
imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, routing ],
declarations: [ AppComponent, SignUpComponent, SignInComponent],
bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
class AppModule {}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);`
```

Comment: Is it angular-cli project??\

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `<base href="/">` in your index.html page as the first line inside head tag

Comment: import { Component } from '@angular/core';

               @Component({
    selector: 'blog',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls:['./app.component.css']
 
    })
    export class AppComponent {
    heading = "Welcome"
    heading2 = "Welcome"
    }

Comment: Try adding <base href="/"> in your index.html page as the first line inside head tag

Answer (score 0):

add `<base href="/">`

You need to add all the js and CSS files in your build file.If it's angular-cli project the you need to configure in .angular-cli.json file.

```
"styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "scripts.js"
],
```